# Has VS 2010 SP1 changed where the .config file is picked up from in VSTO add ins?

Tags: web-services, vsto, visual-studio-2010

I have an outlook 2010 add-in that has a service reference to a simple web service we have set up.
The config for the service is in the app.config file.
This add-in is deployed using windows installer into the program files folder.

This has been working without a problem until yesterday.

Yesterday I installed VS 2010 SP1 and now when the add-in tries to access the web service it has the error **"Could not find default endpoint element that references contract  in the ServiceModel client configuration section."**

Does anyone know what has changed and what is causing this problem?

If I open the project in VS, build and then run from within VS the config is picked up fine.

Thanks
Gavin

Comment: I'm observing the same behavior in an Excel Add-In built with Visual Studio 2010 SP1. If I install my add-in code to C:\Program Files\AddIn, it cannot load because it cannot find the configuration file.  However, by just copying the files into C:\AddIns and changing the "Manifest" registry entry to point to th new location, it works correctly.  That doesn't seem like intentional behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact same problem.  After installing Visual Studio sp1 (which installs VSTO 4 sp1), my Outlook addin could no longer find its config file for service endpoints.  The only solution I've found so far is to run the VSTO setup (the new one) and choose uninstall, then run the old version that was previously installed and rebuild the setup package.  If the new version is installed on the *client machine*, that machine will have this issue.  Your setup may not detect it because typically you specify a minimum version for it to look for. I haven't found any other info about others having this problem besides yourself or anything official from MS about the problem.

Comment: This worked for me on an XP machine but on Windows 7 if VSTO 10.0.31007 gets installed, it stays broken.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/655549/breaking-changes-for-vsto-outlook-addins-that-use-wcf-with-vsto-4-0-sp1-runtime#tabs
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653444/visual-studio-sp1-or-specifically-vsto-sp1-issue-with-config-file-location

Answer (score 3):

The actual solution is more simple.  There was a breaking change made to VSTO 4 sp1 in that the manifest has to be a fully qualified URI.  So when building your setup project, you must prefix the path to the manifest with file:/// and everything works as you'd expect again.  They didn't get the documentation and tutorial pages updated in time for the release.  I'm not sure that they have been yet.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're hitting a problem with extensionless services after installing SP1? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871 - Issue 16?